# Cannot assign to a member of type int[10]

Tags: c++

I have some simple code like the example bellow.

How can I use `this` in this code? And why doesn't the assignment compile?

```
class Deque {
private:
    int deque[10];
    // ...

public:
    void setDeque(); 
    // ...
};

void Deque::setDeque() {
    this->deque = {0}; // ... error on this line ....
                       // 'int [10]' is not assignable
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't assign to an array, but you can *initialize* it.

If you want to set an array to a specific value, then use e.g. [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill):

```
std::fill(std::begin(deque), std::end(deque), 0);  // Set all elements of the array to zero
```

You can also use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which *is* assignable like you want.

Answer (score 5):

You might use `std::array<int, 10>` which is assignable.

Else you have to loop (in some way):

```
void Deque::setDeque() {
    // std::fill_n(this->deque, 10, 0);
    for (auto& v : this->deque) {
        v = 0;
    }
}
```